# How do you match Columns based on Column headers in excel Power Query

Tags: excel, powerquery

I am quite new to Power Query so forgive me if this is obvious. I have 3 files in a folder and have imported them all into excel using "Get data from folder". (I have put my tables at the bottom of the question)

When they are appended to each other they match based on the column rather then the column name. See below:

[image: Image of My current failure]

I was wondering if/how I could append these files using the column header rather then the column itself. So for example all the "Test2" columns would be in column 2.

Tables:

```
+-------+-------+-------+
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| a     | aa    | aaa   |
| b     | bb    | bbb   |
| c     | cc    | ccc   |
+-------+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+-------+
| Test1 | Test2 | Test3 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| d     | dd    | ddd   |
| e     | ee    | eee   |
| f     | ff    | fff   |
+-------+-------+-------+

+-------+-------+-------+
| Test1 | Test3 | Test2 |
+-------+-------+-------+
| g     | ggg   | gg    |
| h     | hhh   | hh    |
| i     | iii   | ii    |
+-------+-------+-------+
```

Edit, extra info for comments:
Once I clicked get data from folder they appeared as below:
[image]

I then added a column with a custom formula(find below) to expand the contents of the file:

= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name]), null, true)

Note that I am trying to get it to work with 3 files, but then I will have to apply it to hundreds of files, so it would be nice if I didn't have to change each file.

The data looks like this:

[image: Image of data table]

Comment: Ideally, you'd want to promote the headers to column names before appending them together. Can you paste the query code?

Comment: You need to create the tables with the desired column headers. Probably your data import method needs to be changed.

Comment: I updated my question to add in some of this info, do you know how I would set my first row as column headers for every sheet?

Answer (score 0):

Some blind advice, since you've not provided your code. Instead of:

```
= Excel.Workbook(File.Contents([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name]), null, true)
```

try:

```
= Excel.Workbook([Content], true, true)
```

(The main change is to pass `true` to the second parameter `useHeaders` instead of `null`, since that may allow the first row to be used as headers.

I believe using `[Content]` is equivalent to using `File.Contents([Folder Path]&"\"&[Name])`. So this isn't a change, just a simplification in code).

---

Also, ensure you're using `Table.Combine` to combine the tables, since that should take care of aligning the column names before appending the tables and get you the output you're expecting.